# MySQL query to retrieve tabular data in json format

Tags: mysql, json

I have a table like below in MySQl database

```
user-name mail
ganesh    g@g.com
gani      gani@gani.com
gan       gan@gan.com
```

I need query to retrieve above table in JSON format

Example:

```
    [{ 
       user-name:"ganesh",
       mail:"g@g.com"
     },
     {
       user-name:"gani",
       mail:"gani@gani.com"
     },
     {
       user-name:"gan",
       mail:"gan@gan.com"
     }
    ]
```

I need help, to do above

Comment: Using which programming language?

Comment: do you want to do this in pure sql ( or more likely ) use a application language

Comment: check [mysql to json tutorial](http://www.thomasfrank.se/mysql_to_json.html)

Comment: @amdixon, this full fills my need... :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not recommended to do such things in the DBMS, do it in the script that is loading the data instead, if you're wrapping some legacy code you can't edit then wrap it with more code to format the data.

If all that fails do something like this: http://www.thomasfrank.se/mysql_to_json.html

```
SELECT 
 CONCAT("[",
      GROUP_CONCAT(
           CONCAT("{username:'",username,"'"),
           CONCAT(",email:'",email),"'}")
      )
 ,"]") 
AS json FROM users;
```

Comment: this is a small play with MYSQL db... thnX